# Proof of a weaker version of Jordan Curve Theorem using induction

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

> Suppose that the sphere $ \mathbb{S}^2 $
>   is given the structure of a closed combinatorial surface.
>   Let $C$ be a subcomplex that is a simplicial circle. Suppose that $ \mathbb{S}^2\backslash C$
>   has two components. Indeed,
>   suppose that this is true for every simplicial circle in $ \mathbb{S}^2
> $
>   . Let $E$ be one of these components.
>
> The aim is to show that $\bar{E}$ is homeomorphic to a disc. Prove this statement by induction on the number of 2-simplices in $\bar{E}$.
>
> **First step**: Let $\sigma _1$ be a 1-simplex in $C$ . Since $\mathbb{S}^2$
>   is a closed combinatorial surface, $\sigma _1$ is adjacent to two
>   2-simplices. Show that precisely one of these 2-simplices lies in $\bar{E}$.
>
> **Second step**: Start the induction by showing that if $\bar{E}$ contains at most one 2-simplex, then $\bar{E}=\sigma_2$
>
> **Third step**:  Let $v$ be the vertex of $\sigma_2$ not lying in $\sigma_1$. Let’s suppose that $v$ does not lie in $C$ . Show how
>   to construct a subcomplex $C'$ of $\mathbb{S}^2$
>   , that is a simplicial circle, and that has the following
>   properties:
>
> - $\mathbb{S}^2\backslash C'$ has two components
> - one of these two components $F$ is a subset of $E$
> - $\bar{F}$ has fewer 2-simplices than $\bar{E}$
>
> Show in this case that $\bar{E}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{D}^2$

The major problem for me is that I don't understand how the induction works for this statement. Can anyone explain the big picture of this induction proof for this statement?

I am quite stuck at the first step. How to show **precisely** one of two 2-simplices? I have a picture on my mind that if you cut a sphere along a simplicial circle, then pick one line (1-simplex) in the simplicial cirle. Of course exactly one triangle (2-simplex) adjacent to this line will be in the half-sphere. But how to say this in a formal way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your first question: Show that, if $v$ is a vertex of degree two in $C$, then the set of components of $\Bbb S^2\setminus C$ incident with one edge are the same as for the other edge ...

Comment: I have proved the first and second step. I am stuck on the third step. I have already found a subcomplex $C'$ that fits the need. However, how to show that $\bar{E}$ is homeomorphic to the unit disk, given that $\bar{F}$ is homeomorphic to the unit disk?